# C++ auto& vs auto

Tags: c++, auto

When creating local variables, is it correct to use `(const) auto&` or `auto`?

e.g.:

```
SomeClass object;
const auto result = object.SomeMethod();
```

or `const auto& result = object.SomeMethod();`

Where SomeMethod() returns a non-primitive value - maybe another user-defined type.
My understanding is that `const auto& result` is correct since the result returned by SomeMethod() would call the copy constructor for the returned type. Please correct me if I am wrong.

What about for primitive types? I assume `const auto sum = 1 + 2;` is correct.

Does this also apply to range based for loops?

```
for(const auto& object : objects)
```

Comment: I highly recommend you to read this: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/ch01.html First two chapters are free and describe template type deduction, which is essentially how `auto` works (except for the peculiar case of `initializer_list`s, which are non-deduced in a template context), then `auto` type deduction.

Answer (score 169):

`auto` and `auto &&` cover most of the cases:

- Use `auto` when you need a local copy. This will never produce a reference. The copy (or move) constructor must exist, but it might not get called, due to the *copy elision* optimization.
- Use `auto &&` when you don't care if the object is local or not. Technically, this will always produce a reference, but if the initializer is a temporary (e.g., the function returns by value), it will behave essentially like your own local object.

  Also, `auto &&` doesn't guarantee that the object will be modifiable, either. Given a `const` object or reference, it will deduce `const`. However, modifiability is often assumed, given the specific context.

`auto &` and `auto const &` are a little more specific:

- `auto &` guarantees that you are sharing the variable with something else. It is always a reference and never to a temporary.
- `auto const &` is like `auto &&`, but provides read-only access.

> What about for primitive/non-primitive types?

There is no difference.

> Does this also apply to range based for loops?

Yes. Applying the above principles,

- Use `auto &&` for the ability to modify and discard values of the sequence within the loop. (That is, unless the container provides a read-only view, such as `std::initializer_list`, in which case it will be effectively an `auto const &`.)
- Use `auto &` to modify the values of the sequence in a meaningful way.
- Use `auto const &` for read-only access.
- Use `auto` to work with (modifiable) copies.

You also mention `auto const` with no reference. This works, but it's not very commonly used because there is seldom an advantage to read-only access to something that you already own.

Comment: Sutter says that auto& tracks constness

Comment: @JessePepper Yes. (It’s a bit odd to appeal to authority though.) Are you referring to a specific part of this?

Comment: In essence `auto&` seems to be a good choice. But using `const auto&` when you want to add constness that isn't already there.

`auto&&` is for forwarding, which I do think happens more often than Sutter thinks.  For example, you might want to store a return value by `auto&&` and then "forward" it to two things, like std::cout to see the value for debugging and also pass it to some other function.

I used to use auto&& more often but have been bitten by it once or twice when it did some unexpected things.  I wish I took more notice of what went wrong!

Comment: @JessePepper Yes, `auto&&` is related of a missing language feature, that *should* allow any statement to be divided into smaller statements. The missing part is lifetime extension… I put quite a bit of effort into fixing this but nobody noticed. Don't put too much stock in punditry :)

Comment: On auto const: It may be more natural to write auto const x = fn(); if you know the function does not return a reference, and you want the object x not to change, to avoid bugs, or document it's use in the scope. In the same way you wouldn't normally write: const int& x  = 1; But auto const & does give equivalent results due to lifetime extension rules for references declared in this way.

Answer (score 77):

Yes, it is correct to use `auto` and `auto&` for local variables.
When getting the return type of a function, it is also correct to use `auto&`. This applies for range based for loops as well.

General rules for using `auto` are:

- Choose `auto x` when you want to work with copies.
- Choose `auto &x` when you want to work with original items and may modify them.
- Choose `auto const &x` when you want to work with original items and will
  not modify them.

You can read more about the auto specifier [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

Comment: thanks, but could you explain further? we have `auto x` to work with copies and use `auto const &x` without needing to modify. So what is the difference between these cases?

Answer (score 16):

`auto` uses the same mechanism of type deduction as templates, the only exception that I am aware of being that of brace-init lists, which are deduced by `auto` as `std::initializer_list`, but non-deduced in a template context.

```
auto x = expression;
```

works by first stripping all reference and cv qualifiers from the type of the right hand side expression, then matching the type. For example, if you have `const int& f(){...}` then `auto x = f();` deduces `x` as `int`, and **not** `const int&`.

The other form,

```
auto& x = expression
```

**does not strip** the cv-qualifiers, so, using the example above, `auto& x = f()` deduces `x` as `const int&`. The other combinations just add cv qualifiers.

If you want your type to be always deduced with cv-ref qualifiers, use the infamous `decltype(auto)` in C++14, which uses the `decltype` type deduction rules.

So, in a nutshell, if you want copies, use `auto`, if you want references, use `auto&`. Use `const` whenever you want additional `const`-ness.

---

**EDIT** 
There is an additional use case,

```
auto&& x = expression;
```

which uses the reference-collapsing rules, same as in the case of forwarding references in template code. If `expression` is a lvalue, then `x` is a lvalue reference with the cv-qualifiers of `expression`. If `expression` is a rvalue, then `x` is a rvalue reference.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Thanks, edited. I actually wonder about the cv for `rvalues`. Is there any simple way of testing? And how can you have a cv-qualified rvalue? On function return cv is discarded.

Comment: No, it is not discarded on function returns. It is discarded for prvalues of all scalar types (C++14 [and other editions] §5/6). You can get one using a function call or cast notation. Cv-qualified xvalues work the same as anything else: `auto && x = std::move< const int >( 5 );` will declare `int const && x`, although they are seldom used.

Comment: @Potatoswatter thanks, you are right, my mistake. I tested first with PODs, in which case the cv is discarded, and thought that's the general case. Of course it shouldn't be discarded, since in general one may want to preserve the cv (e.g. so one cannot call non-const member function on rvalue returns).

Comment: Discarded for scalar types. PODs may be classes. Anyway, it's a hackish corner of the intersection of the expression model and the object model.

Answer (score 2):

> When creating local variables, is it correct to use (const) auto& or auto?

Yes. The auto is nothing more than a compiler-deduced type, so use references where you would normally use references, and local (automatic) copies where you would normally use local copies. Whether or not to use a reference is independent of type deduction.

> Where SomeMethod() returns a non-primitive value - maybe another user-defined type. My understanding is that const auto& result is correct since the result returned by SomeMethod() would call the copy constructor for the returned type. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Legal? Yes, with the const. Best practice? Probably not, no. At least, not with C++11. Especially not, if the value returned from SomeMethod() is already a temporary. You'll want to learn about C++11 move semantics, copy elision, and return value optimization:
https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/want-speed-dont-always-pass-by-value/

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=199

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#return-by-value-optimization

> What about for primitive types? I assume const auto sum = 1 + 2; is correct.

Yes, this is fine.

> Does this also apply to range based for loops?
>
> for(const auto& object : objects)

Yes, this is also fine. I write this sort of code at work all the time.