# Why is my map's second value not modifying?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm working on a chatroom program, and I am trying to add a user to a chatroom map.  My chatroom map is stored in my `Server` class and it looks like this: `map<Chatroom*,int> chatrooms` where int is the number of users in the chatroom.  Also in my `Server` class is a vector of all the users currently in the server:

`vector<User*> current_users`. `server.getUsers()` returns the `current_users` and `server.get_chatrooms()` returns the map `chatrooms`. My function properly adds the user to the chatroom, however, it doesn't increment the number of users in the chatroom. I wrote a comment where the problem is.

Here is the function.

```
void Controller::add_user_to_chatroom(){
    string username, chatroom_name;
    User* user;
    bool foundChat = false;
    bool foundUser = false;

    view.username_prompt();
    cin >> username;

    //this loops checks to see if user is on the server 
    for(auto x : server.get_users()){
        if(x->getUsername() == username){
            user = x;
            foundUser = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!foundUser){
        cout << "No user found.\n" << endl;
    }
    else{
        view.chatroom_name_prompt();
        cin >> chatroom_name;

        //adds user to chatroom, but doesn't increment the number
        for(auto x : server.get_chatrooms()){
            if(x.first->get_name() == chatroom_name){
                x.first->add_user(user);

                //line below doesn't work, tried x.second++;
                server.get_chatrooms().at(x.first) += 1;
                foundChat = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!foundChat){
            cout << "Chatroom not found.\n" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

My output when there I print chatrooms looks like this:
`Chatroom Name: Sports, Users: joey1212, , Num Users: 0`

However, it should look like this:
`Chatroom Name: Sports, Users: joey1212, , Num Users: 1` since there is one user in the chatroom.

Why is `x.second` not updating? I've added several users to the same chatroom and num users never updates.  Just in case it's needed, here are the other functions that were called from `add_user_to_chatroom()`

Here's `Server::get_users()`

```
vector<User*> Server::get_users(){
    return users;
}
```

Here's `Server::get_chatrooms()`

```
 map<Chatroom*, int> Server::get_chatrooms(){
    return chatrooms;
 }
```

Comment: Think you need auto& https://stackoverflow.com/a/29860056/360211 or you're modifying a local copy of the map entry, not the map entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_chatrooms` returns a *copy* of the map.  When you try to change the number of users in a room, you're changing the value in the copy and not the one in `server.chatrooms`.

Change `get_chatrooms` to return a reference:

```
map<Chatroom*, int> &Server::get_chatrooms()
```

Comment: Now that I think about it... why does it work for get_users() if it's only getting a copy of the users and not the reference?  What is the difference between get_users() and get_chatrooms() for the different behavior?

Comment: @rbb091020 Since `get_users` returns a `vector<User *>`, it doesn't matter if you use a copy or a reference to the original - you get the same user pointers.  `get_chatrooms` returns a map, and when you iterate thru that you get the same `x.first` (because both pointers have the same value), but `x.second` refers to different ints.