# c++ iterating with auto reference

Tags: c++

Although having read a bunch of posts here, I still often make mistakes in using `auto&` reference in  `for (auto& x : some_container)` . Usually, to avoid constructing temporary copy and speed up for-loop iteration for string types, I use `auto&` as a default option.

Could someone please guide me on when and how to correctly use `auto&`?

EDIT:

Below may be a bad example. I know we shall avoid vector from the book effective c++. However, this question also asks for general guidelines for using auto& iterating containers

Today, I fall into another error trap of using `auto&`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    vector<bool> vec(n, false);
    for(auto& x : vec) cout << x << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error message is show as below. What does it mean?

```
vector_bool.cpp:9:15: error: non-const lvalue reference to type '__bit_reference<[2 * ...]>' cannot bind to
      a temporary of type '__bit_reference<[2 * ...]>'
    for(auto& x : vec) cout << x << " ";
              ^ ~
```

Comment: The trap is using `vector<bool>`.  If you can, you should avoid it.  It is not like a regular vector.

Comment: Thanks, I know that from effective c++. However, this question also asks for general guidelines for using auto& iterating containers.

Comment: Take a read of [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

Comment: It's fine for everything except `vector<bool>`.

Comment: In hindsight, they should have made a space-optimized std::vector_bool ... but too late now, that ship has sailed.

Comment: `auto &` =  I want to modify and not copy. `const auto &` = I want to not copy. `auto` = I want to copy and modify. `const auto` = I want to copy.

Comment: For your question, it is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859796/c-auto-vs-auto