# Recursive lambda: pass by reference or universal reference?

Tags: c++, lambda, pass-by-reference

When I need to implement a recursive lambda, usually I do it like this:

```
auto factorial = [](auto& self, int n) -> int {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * self(self, n - 1);
};
```

and call it with `factorial(factorial, n)`. However, I've seen people declaring the parameter `self` with type `auto&&` instead of `auto&`. What's the difference?

Comment: no real difference in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the difference?

The lvalue reference to non-const of your example cannot bind to rvalues.

> and call it with factorial(factorial, n)

If you don't ever intend pass an rvalue, then the difference is of no practical consequence.

Answer (score 1):

As @appleapple said,

> no real difference in your case

That is correct. If you want to know a bit more, perhaps this will interest you: [C++ auto& vs auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859796/c-auto-vs-auto)