# cin didnt work in range based loop in vector

Tags: c++

I tried to input values to my vector,but it filled with zero value.
I try to input value by following range based loop and output them.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define REP(i,n) for(int i=0; i<(n); i++)
 
int main() {
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    vector<int>A(N);
    for(auto x:A) cin>>x;
    for(auto y:A) cout<<y<<' ';
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output is following , `N=2` `vector=1 2` but output is `0 0`

```
root@DESKTOP-TM0ASL2:~/work# ./a.out 
2   
1 2
0 0
```

What is the root cause of this ?
I worked for a while, but I haven't understood yet, if someone has opinion, will you please let me know. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: `auto x` >> `auto& x` . `cin` is "work"ing fine. You're just discarding all the values you're reading; one at a time.

Comment: While you don't use it, macros like `REP` doesn't do anything good for your code. It doesn't make it quicker, it doesn't make it easier to read and understand. Shortcut-macros like that is only taught by people and places that arean't mean to be teaching programming.

Comment: please do not include bits/stdc++, its never needed and will not work on some platforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem does not relate to `std::cin` at all. The problem is the way you used `auto` in the range based loop.

In order to update the `std::vector`, you should change:

```
for(auto x:A) cin>>x;
```

to:

```
for(auto & x:A) cin>>x;  // NOTE: added '&'
```

Because the meaning  of `auto` does not include "reference-ness" (even if the expression assigned to the `auto` is in fact a reference). See more info here: [C++ auto& vs auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859796/c-auto-vs-auto). This is the more "formal" description (a bit harder to understand): [cppreference.com - auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto). The bottom line is that `auto` will be deduced by the compiler to be `int` in your case (not `int&`).

Therefore in your code, `x` in the loop is getting a copy of the element from `A`, which is filled by `cin` (i.e. the `vector` is not modified).

Same applies to `const`ness. Therefore when you print the `std::vector`, it's better to do something like:

```
for(auto const & y:A) cout<<y<<' ';  // NOTE: added 'const &'
```

This will cause the compiler to ensure that `A`'s elements are not modified in the loop (due to `const`) and be efficient (using reference [`&`] will avoid coping the elements).

Some other notes:

1. Better to avoid `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - see here: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).
2. Better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).